# Verify the valid value is displayed for the account holder and sorted by order in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium

I am writing a automation script and following BDD Framework with Cucumber, Selenium WebDriver. I don't how to verify the web page display correct code and if there are multiple rows that code display by sorted order.
Test case:

```
Given that the Account Holder page is displayed,
When the user clicks on any member record
Then the latest  information will be retrieved and displayed on the 'Record Page' page under the 'Financial' section:
    Field Name - Financial Code - Indicates the 3-Character code  that represents the type. 
    Valid values are: CBP, EBP, FBP, MNP, NNP, ONP.
```

I have to verify that Account holder have correct code out of mentioned valid value and and if there are multiple row that display by sorted order.

## Here is my code:

```
public void verifyAccountHolderCode(WebDriver driver, By xpath,String Value) {
    String ContrctCode = driver.findElement(xpath).getText();
   if (ContrctCode.equals("CBP")) {
        Assert.assertTrue(ContrctCode .contains(Value));  //Value represent      the correct code which will be provided in Step Definition
        System.out.println("Correct code displayed");
    } else if (ContrctCode .contains("EBP")) {
        Assert.assertTrue(ContrctCode .contains(Value));
        System.out.println("Correct code displayed");
    } else if (ContrctCode.contains("FBP")) {
        Assert.assertTrue(ContrctCode.contains(Value));
        System.out.println("Correct code displayed");
    } else if (ContrctCode.contains("MNP")) {
        Assert.assertTrue(ContrctCode.contains(Value));
        System.out.println("Correct code displayed");
    } else if (ContrctCode.equals("NNP")) {
        Assert.assertTrue(ContrctCode.contains(Value));
        System.out.println("Correct code displayed");
    } else if (ContrctCode.contains("ONP")) {
        Assert.assertTrue(ContrctCode.contains(Value));
        System.out.println("Correct code displayed");

    } else if (ContrctCode.equals("- -")) {
        Assert.assertTrue(ContrctCode.contains(Value));
        System.out.println("No code displayed");
    }
}
```

## Step Definition:

```
@Then("^Account Infomation displayed under the Financial Tab$")
public void AccountInfo() {

    AccountHolderPage AccountCode = AccountHolderPage();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(AccountCode.Xpath_1)).click();
    AccountCode.verifyAccountHolderCode(driver,
            AccountCode.(Xpath for valid value), "EBP");
```

Comment: What is your question?  Does your code fail?  what is the error?

Comment: Are you using the C# driver?

Comment: Thanks, got solution